# Python Adding Unknown Values to Lists

Tags: python, list

I have made a treasure hunt game, and I need it so that once a square containing a treasure chest has been visited 3 times it turns into a 'bandit'.
In order to covunt the number of times a treasure chest has been visited, I added another lot of the same coordinates to the list of TreasureChestCoordinates. Then I plan to have an if statement so that if any of the coordinates are written 3 times, all 3 will be removed and put in the 'bandit' list.
Here's my draft code for the section:

```
            # Treasure Chests Collecting Coins #
        if (x,y) in TreasureCoords[0:(TCNumber -1)]:
            print("You have landed on a treasure chest! You can visit it 2 more times before it becomes a bandit.")
            CoinCollection = CoinCollection + 10
            TreasureCoords.append(x,y)

        #if TreasureCoords.count(any item) > 3:
            #remove all copies of item from list
            #add item to bandit list
```

x,y means the coordinates the user is currently in. CoinCollection is a seperate variable that changes when the user lands on a treasure chest or bandit.By the way, the number of coordinates is unlimited because the user decides that earlier on in the game.
So, how can I duplicate my list of coordinates, remove them once they are in the list 3 times and put them in a new list? I presume this is the easiest way to 'count' how many times the user has been on a square, and change the treasure chest to a bandit.

Comment: No, this sounds like an unnecessarily complicated way of doing it. It would be simpler to just keep a mapping from coordinate to number of visits.

Comment: Also, the number of coordinates you have in your list cannot be "unlimited" because you don't have unlimited memory...

Comment: Sorry was just trying to illustrate my point - as you can probably tell I'm not a particularly advanced coder... How would you solution work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First... you don't need to search the list for *any* coordinate present three times. That's wasteful. If you remove them once that happens, then the only coordinate that can possibly be present three times is the one you just visited.

If you *really* want to do it as shown in your question, just do something like `while (x,y) in TreasureCoords: TreasureCoords.remove((x,y))`. However, it would probably be easier to use a `dict`. You can probably avoid having separate variables, even. Assuming that `ItemCoords` is initially filled with coordinates that represent unvisited treasure chests:

```
ItemCoords[(x,y)] = 0 # add a treasure
```

...then you can just look at how many times the treasure is visited:

```
visits = ItemCoords.get((x,y), None)
if visits is None:
    pass # nothing there
else if visits > 3:
    fightBandit() # ...or whatever
else:
    print("You have landed on a treasure chest! You can visit it %i more times before it becomes a bandit." % (2 - visits))
    CoinCollection += 10
    ItemCoords[(x,y)] += 1
```

This is still simplistic. You probably want a more object-oriented approach as hinted at by Christian:

```
class Treasure:
    def __init__(x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.visits = 0

    def visit():
        print("You have landed on a treasure chest! You can visit it %i more times before it becomes a bandit." % (2 - visits))    
        CoinCollection += 10

        if visits == 3:
            world[(self.x, self.y)] = Bandit(self.x, self.y)

class Bandit:
    def __init__(x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def visit():
        # Replace this with whatever happens when the player meets a bandit
        print("You have been eaten by a grue.")
        sys.exit(0)

# Initialize the world
for n in range(NumberOfTreasure):
    # get x,y somehow, e.g. random
    world[(x,y)] = Treasure(x,y)

# ...code for player wandering around...
here = world.get((x,y), None)
if here is not None:
    here.visit()
```

Comment: I implemented your 1st code, and changed itemCoords to TreasureCoords, which is the list name that stores all the treasure chest coordinates. However when I played the game, this error appeared "TreasureCoords[(x,y)] = 0
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple" can you help/do you know what this means?

Comment: You probably initialized `TreasureCoords` like `= []`, which makes it a `list`. My modified code uses a `dict` instead, so you need to initialize it like `= {}` or `= dict()`.

Comment: Ok. Does that mean I need to change all my other lists into dictionaries too? Will I need to change anything else, or does everything work the same with a dictionary?

Comment: It depends how you use them; a `list` is... well, a list. It has items, they are in some order, you can access them by index. A `dict` is a map. Maps in general may or may not present their items as being in any particular order, but each item has an associated key, and you look up items by key. The key in this case is the location of the item in the world.

Comment: Currently, my TreasureCoords and BanditCoords are lists, as they both have 'A' amount of values for the X coordinates and 'B' amount of values for the Y coordinates to determine their position. By changing them into dictionaries, I don't think this would be beneficial as I would have to then determine a key - and as the number of values in the (current) list is set by the user, this could be very complicated. What do you suggest? Your second code would be a lot harder to implement into my current code, so I'd rather not use that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a case where an object would be beneficial - instead of tracking separate lists with facts about the same thing, use an list of objects which store all relevant information.

Could look like this:

```
class Monster(object):
    #define like you like it
    pass

class Treasure(object):
   def init(x, y):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y
      self.visits = 0

    def visit():
        self.visits += 1

        if self.visits >= 3:
            return Monster()
        else:
            return 10


calling code:
    treasure = Treasure(1,1)
    rv = treasure.visit()
    if isinstance(rv, Monster):
        # lets the monster rip him to shreds
    else:
        CoinCollection +=treasure.visit()
```

Comment: Can I still use that code without knowing how many treasure chests there are? The user sets the number of treasure chests elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Of course - you would have to create a list of Treasures of a similar length. Honestly, that's the critical skill your software course tries to teach you - how to structure a big program which consists of modular pieces which work in concert to achieve a goal.